# Developer warning for package "com.instagram.android"

Tags: android, warnings, instagram

I downloaded instagram app from playstore and it is showing a warning like the one in the screenshot.

[image]

The warning pops up every time there is any message or notification on Instagram.

Could it be because of the custom rom I have installed based on android pie on my device Redmi Note 4?

The warning is very annoying and is not even transparent moreover it takes a lot of time before disappearing. Can someone please help? I'm not a techie, it would be better if you can give me steps to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

That is android Toast message(like popup alert) .Dont worry about it. Normally Developer use for it find out the issues or debug the apps or display messages.i think your device have some problem. you should comment this issue to playstore app review section.

Answer (score 0):

Just uninstall and install the Instagram again from the Google Play Store only.
Although it is just the Toast message, developers use this to get the status of functionalities working or not.

No need to worry about this thing.
Thanks!

Comment: I tried that, it's still showing up every time and is really frustrating.

Comment: Uninstall the Application from your device. Then try below steps-
Go to File Manager > Internal Storage > folder Android > folder Data 

find the folder by "com.instagram.android" and delete it manually.
Then, try to install the Application again. :)